# Can't center elements using React/JS/M

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I can't align my elements to which they are in the middle of my page. I want **3** elements per row, and n rows as needed depending on the number of "VideoBox"es. I need it to fit within the lettering of the **P R O F E S S I O N A L    P R O J E C T S** title. (see image below)

I am not that great at JS/TS/CSS/React, so any advice will be helpful!

I have attached all the involved code.

```
/*VideoFile.tsx*/
import React from 'react';
import './VideoFile.css'


export default function VideoBox({ name, image, link, release, popularity }) {
  return (
    <div>
        <div className="box">
            <img src={image} alt={name} />
        </div>
        <div className ="img-name">{name}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export { VideoBox };
```

```
/*VideoFile.css*/
  .box {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .box a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none; 
  }
  
  .box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  .img-name {
    color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 2px; 
    margin-right:100px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-size: px;
    max-width: 207px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
  }
```

```
/*Professional Projects.js*/
import React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import VideoBox from 'C:/Users/gavdog/VSC/ColtonWebsite/src/components/VideoFile.tsx';
import './Page.css';

export default function Home() {
  const videoFiles = [
    { name: 'Awesome Adventure', image: '/IMG_9676.jpg', link: '#', release: '2023-01-01', popularity: 80 },
    { name: 'Fantastic Journey', image: '/IMG_9676.jpg', link: '#', release: '2023-02-15', popularity: 92 },
    { name: 'Epic Exploration', image: '/IMG_9676.jpg', link: '#', release: '2023-03-21', popularity: 65 },
    { name: 'Amazing Discovery', image: '/IMG_9676.jpg', link: '#', release: '2023-04-10', popularity: 87 },
    { name: 'Cool Quest', image: '/IMG_9676.jpg', link: '#', release: '2023-05-05', popularity: 75 },
    { name: 'Unbelievable Voyage', image: '/IMG_9676.jpg', link: '#', release: '2023-06-18', popularity: 89 },
    { name: 'Incredible Expedition', image: '/IMG_9676.jpg', link: '#', release: '2023-07-30', popularity: 78 },
    { name: 'Exciting Trek', image: '/IMG_9676.jpg', link: '#', release: '2023-08-22', popularity: 94 },
    { name: 'Breathtaking Safari', image: '/IMG_9676.jpg', link: '#', release: '2023-09-14', popularity: 82 },
    { name: 'Adventurous Safari', image: '/IMG_9676.jpg', link: '#', release: '2023-10-09', popularity: 88 },
  ];

  

  return (
    <div className="gradient_background">
        <div className="title">Professional Work</div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <Box sx={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: '30%',
          mx: "auto"
        }}>
            <Grid container spacing={0} mx="auto" zIndex='tooltip'>
                {videoFiles.map((video, index) => (
                    <Grid key={index} xs={4}>
                        <VideoBox
                            name={video.name}
                            image={video.image}
                            link={video.link}
                            release={video.release}
                            popularity={video.popularity}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
        </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
/*Page.css*/
.gradient_background {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #010101, #161616);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 99vw;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.title {
    font-family: 'Harmony', harmony;
    font-size: 52px;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #f3f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 1.25rem;
    padding-right: 1.25rem;
    padding-top: 7rem;
    padding-bottom: 0rem;
}
.trailer{
    font-family: 'Westmount', Westmount;
    font-size: 41px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #f3f1f1;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 1px auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 6rem;
}

.trailer::before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 130px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18%;
    left: 0;
    background: #dbdbdb;
}
  
.trailer::after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 130px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18%;
    right: 0;
    background: #f3f1f1;
    
}

.sec{
    font-family: 'MagnumSans', magnumsans;
    font-size: 36px;
    letter-spacing: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #f7f4f4;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center; 
    height: 86vh;
}
.center-content {
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    border: 2px solid #fffefe;
    width: 450px; 
}

.box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
    object-fit: fill;
    display: block;
}

.text-group {
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 1.4rem;
    font-family: 'MagnumSans', magnumsans;
    font-size: 24.6px;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #f3f1f1;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}

.sec {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.link{
    color: #FFFFFF
}
.link:hover{
    color: #f5ebeb;
    transform: scale(1.2)
}
```

And here is an image of what it currently looks like

[Ignore the 404s they are just place holder pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80cQv.png)

Comment: I find that when I have "a lot of code" and things aren't aligning the way I want, the better move is to make a smaller, simpler working version then build it back up.  Otherwise you are just flailing around in a huge codebase.  I create "example" projects a couple of times a day.  `npx create-vite@latest` is seared into my typing fingers :)

Answer (score 0):

I would work to maximize the use of MUI, lower the usage of CSS styles until you have the fundamentals aligned and working as you so desire.

Consider taking your 1-dimensional array of videoFiles and creating a new 2-dimensional grid (3 x N).

```js
import { Grid, Container, Paper, Typography } from '@mui/material';

const testUrl =
  'https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/237/200/200.jpg?hmac=zHUGikXUDyLCCmvyww1izLK3R3k8oRYBRiTizZEdyfI';

// Sample data
const videoFiles = [
  {name: 'Awesome Adventure', imageUrl: testUrl, link: '#', release: '2023-01-01', popularity: 80},
  {name: 'Fantastic Journey', imageUrl: testUrl, link: '#', release: '2023-02-15', popularity: 92},
  {name: 'Epic Exploration', imageUrl: testUrl, link: '#', release: '2023-03-21', popularity: 65},
  {name: 'Amazing Discovery', imageUrl: testUrl, link: '#', release: '2023-04-10', popularity: 87},
  {name: 'Cool Quest', imageUrl: testUrl, link: '#', release: '2023-05-05', popularity: 75},
  {name: 'Unbelievable Voyage', imageUrl: testUrl, link: '#', release: '2023-06-18', popularity: 89},
  {name: 'Incredible Expedition', imageUrl: testUrl, link: '#', release: '2023-07-30', popularity: 78},
  {name: 'Exciting Trek', imageUrl: testUrl, link: '#', release: '2023-08-22', popularity: 94},
  {name: 'Breathtaking Safari', imageUrl: testUrl, link: '#', release: '2023-09-14', popularity: 82},
  {name: 'Adventurous Safari', imageUrl: testUrl, link: '#', release: '2023-10-09', popularity: 88},
];

const arrayToGrid = (arr, elementsPerRow) => {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += elementsPerRow) {
    result.push(arr.slice(i, i + elementsPerRow));
  }
  return result;
};

const videoGrid = arrayToGrid(videoFiles, 3);

// Component for showing Video data with details
const VideoBox = ({ name, imageUrl }) => (
  <Paper
    elevation={3}
    style={{
      padding: 16,
      textAlign: 'center',
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
    }}
  >
    <img
      src={imageUrl}
      alt={name}
      style={{ maxWidth: '100%', height: 'auto', marginBottom: 8 }}
    />
    <Typography variant='subtitle1'>{name}</Typography>
  </Paper>
);

// Main component rendering the grid
const Home = () => (
  <Container maxWidth='md' style={{ marginTop: 16 }}>
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      {videoGrid.map((row) =>
        row.map((vidData, idx) => (
          <Grid key={idx} item xs={12} sm={4}>
            <VideoBox {...vidData} />
          </Grid>
        ))
      )}
    </Grid>
  </Container>
);

export default Home;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't discover the greatness of MUI until just recently in my development, I've been so dependent on CSS. Do you think I should depend on other imports like MUI or Chakra until I get more confident in my JS and CSS skills?

Comment: CSS is cool, but at the end of the day if all you are doing is trying to make something look and feel consistent, then I highly recommend going with an existing styled component library.  That gives you consistency of UX across the app, and frequently can be consistently adjusted by creating or extending a "theme" within the library.  Leverage the many-many-many person hours/years that others have put into the library, so you can focus on building "value" for your app and not just "plumbing".